# Z.sh Directory jumper - Change where history is kept

Tags: shell, zsh

Using [z](https://github.com/rupa/z) in zsh, I want to change the default location of where the history is kept.

By default, when your source the shell script

```
source ~/z/z.sh
```

It will make a file with the directories you visit in a `.z/` directory. While this is fine for most cases, I want to change this to another directory. The `README.md` does state that you can set some variables for this in my `.zshrc`

```
Optionally:
          Set $_Z_DATA to change the datafile (default $HOME/.z).
```

So I added this

```
export $_Z_DATA="$HOME/.z-history"
```

But for some reason, I get a warning that my shell can't find the directory. 
Any idea why this is happening? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having a typo, or haven't yet get how the bash variable works.

You do not need to use `$` when declaring a variable. Only when you want to access it.

So just adapt you config with:

```
export _Z_DATA="$HOME/.z-history"
```

*voilà* :) it should works

Comment: derp, knew it must have been something stupid like that. Thanks a lot